# How to add Post Format Taxonomy Archive page in the menu?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, taxonomy, archives, post-formats

I have customized the archive template for the post format using the Wordpress template file structure.

I have the file: `taxonomy-post_format.php` which works fine.

The page is then accessible through `http://example.com/type/{post-format}`

But I can't seem to find a way to add the post format archive page as a menu item.

Comment: Have you tried entering the URL `http://example.com/type/{post-format}` under *Appearance > Menus > Custom Links*?

Comment: @DaveRomsey I know this but this won't hightlight the page when it is active.

Comment: It should. When visiting `http://example.com/type/link` the custom menu item with the URL `http://example.com/type/link` will have the class `current-menu-item`. It's up to the them to style it. (verified working on Twenty Seventeen). If this isn't happening then perhaps it's a theme styling issue or theme/plugin could be altering the default behavior of WP.